# Jumbotron too wide in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

See: http://jsfiddle.net/rMYdL/

My jumbotron seems to be exceeding the width of `col-md-10` (meaning, I see a horizontal scroll bar). Any ideas why? Here's the relevant snippet:

```
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>
          Hello
        </h1>
        <p>
          Please select the type of post you would like to add, edit, or delete.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It looks like your body is too wide in this fiddle, not jumbotron.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are putting a `.container` inside a `.col-*`. You should use a `.row` instead.

And you also dont have any `.container` before the first `.row` on your `<body>`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rMYdL/1/)**

Comment: I would probably recommend that you use a `.col-md-12` inside that `.row` in `.jumbotron` as well, so you avoid the padding/margin issues.

Comment: I used `.container-fluid` and `.row-fluid` instead. Putting `.col-md-12` per your comment kindda broke things. I think it's good now as is.

Comment: Here's a cleaner solution, no need for a new row inside the jumbotron: http://jsfiddle.net/MxBJ3/

Comment: Can you please tell me which line numbers to look at? Not sure if I see what you did.

Comment: There is no `.container-fluid` or `.row-fluid` in Bootstrap v3. You are using v3 in that Fiddle.

Comment: And thats correct, you dont need a new `.row` inside `.jumbotron`. I just replaced it because you had a `.container` there. Usually after a `.row` you should use a `.col-*`, or you most likely will have wrong padding going on.

Comment: Should have read the text above!! :) - To make the jumbotron full width, don't include it within a `.container`. Placing it within a container will keep it at the width of the rest of your content and provide rounded corners.

Comment: Oh, I see.. Actually you could keep that `.container` there... The main issue was that you didnt have a `.container` for the rest of your content :)